# Bug report nltk.translate.bleu_score stopped working on tokens less than or equal to 3

Tags: nltk, bug-reporting, bleu

Plat form Windows 11 Anaconda

```
import nltk as nltk
nltk.__version__
'3.8.1'
```

The `sentence_bleu` ought to return 1 for identical translation

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu, SmoothingFunction
sentence_bleu([["hi", "hello", "world"]], ["hi", "hello", "world"])
1.2213386697554703e-77
```

and even with a smooth function it could not help much

```
smoother = SmoothingFunction()
sentence_bleu([["hi", "hello", "world"]], ["hi", "hello", "world"], smoothing_function=smoother.method4)
0.5757197301274735
```

However,

```
sentence_bleu([["hi", "hello", "world", "how"]], ["hi", "hello", "world", "how"])
1.0
```

This appeared to be a bug in case handling or the summation index.

Comment: I don't see a question here. If you're reporting a bug, contact the library or project developers. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.).